# discrepancy in numbers of installed modules between ipython and ipython notebook

Tags: python, import, jupyter

Hi I have a curious (and maybe trivial who knows?) problem.

For the requirements of a course on coursera I have created a python 2.7 environment in my anaconda distribution and installed DATOs' GraphLab Create modules.

While the simple "import graphlab" functions properly  from the python command line or the ipython console it fails in a jupyter notebook.

checking installed modules with pip.get_installed_distributions() yields 148 modules in ipython console and only 42 in the jupyter notebook!

So, what is at work here? :-)

Thanks for any hint,

Alain

Comment: are the version numbers same? as reported by `python`  > `exit()` > `ipython` > `exit()`

Comment: Thanks for the hint. The python version are the same in all three cases. But you got me thinking and I checked sys.path and BINGO! for some reason "ipython notebook" called in env A picks up another environment B. and ipython console does not.

Answer (score 1):

As you said you have created an environment with Python 2.7, you thus **need to register** this environment with the notebook.

Activate the environement:

```
$ source activate myenv
```

Then install the kernelspec for this environment:

```
(myenv)$ python -m ipykernel install --name myenv
```

You will need to install `ipykernel` in this env if it is not installed.

Now when starting a notebook, you can create a new notebook using this env, and/or change the currently used `env`, using the `Kernel` menu.